# Keras doesn't predict multi output correctly

Tags: python, keras, regression, lstm, prediction

I have a dataset with two features to predict those two features. Here and example of data:

```
raw = {'one':  ['41.392953', '41.392889', '41.392825','41.392761', '41.392697'],
        'two': ['2.163917','2.163995','2.164072','2.164150','2.164229' ]}
```

When I'm using Keras (below my code):

```
# example of making predictions for a regression problem
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
X = raw[:-1]
y = raw[1:]
# define and fit the final model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X[0:len(X)-1], y[0:len(y)-1], epochs=1000, verbose=0)
# make a prediction
Xnew=X[len(X)-1:len(X)]
ynew = model.predict(Xnew)
# show the inputs and predicted outputs
print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (Xnew, ynew))
```

However, the output is different from the input, it should contain two parameters and with similar size.

```
X=        latitude  longitude
55740  41.392052   2.164564, Predicted=[[21.778254]]
```

Comment: What is the shape of X and Y in your dataset? And are you expecting coordinates as your output?

Comment: X and Y are coordinates, X samples and Y classes (using the same samples). The output must be coordinates as well.

Comment: Ok, and again, what is the shape of X and Y in your dataset?

Comment: (341, 2) both X and y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have two outputs, you have to explicitly specify them in your output layer. For example:

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

X = tf.random.normal((341, 2))
Y = tf.random.normal((341, 2))
# define and fit the final model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=1, verbose=0)
# make a prediction
Xnew=tf.random.normal((1, 2))
ynew = model.predict(Xnew)
# show the inputs and predicted outputs
print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (Xnew, ynew))
# X=tf.Tensor([[-0.8087067  0.5405918]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32), Predicted=[[-0.02120915 -0.0466493 ]]
```

Comment: I've changed input_dim to 2, however, I get uniquely one value. My Xnew variable is a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame with two values.

Comment: `input_dim` was already 2. Check the code in your original question. What I changed is this: `model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear')). Note the number 2.
`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your input format. Why do you not use 4 for input dimensions?

I try with different format (numpy). The output is quite good.

```
import numpy as np
raw = np.array([[41.392953, 41.392889, 41.392825,41.392761, 41.392697],
        [2.163917,2.163995,2.164072,2.164150,2.164229 ]])
# example of making predictions for a regression problem
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
X = raw[:,:-1]
y = raw[:,-1]
# define and fit the final model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=1000, verbose=0)
# make a prediction
Xnew=X[len(X)-1:len(X)]
ynew = model.predict(Xnew)
# show the inputs and predicted outputs
print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (Xnew, ynew))
```

Outputs:

```
X=[[2.163917 2.163995 2.164072 2.16415 ]], Predicted=[[2.3935468]]
```

Comment: My prediction should be two features: one and two

Comment: I'm looking for sth similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079455/keras-lstm-input-predicting-a-parabolic-trajectory but 2D

Answer (score 0):

If you define your data like that:

```
raw = np.array([[41.392953, 41.392889, 41.392825,41.392761, 41.392697],
        [2.163917,2.163995,2.164072,2.164150,2.164229 ]])
X = raw[:,:-1]
y = raw[:,-1]
```

There will be a regression with 4 features, 2 samples and 1 label:
[image]

For multiple outputs just set your final layer like that:
`model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='linear'))`

When `n_classes` can be any number you like.